# pass multiple value from recyclerview to main activity when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a gym app,Items are displayed as below.There is add button and next button in layout.
when i click on add button which is in recycler-view,the text of button changes to added and remove button is visible as shown in image below.
now when i click on next button,all the added items text must be passes to my mainActivity.

i dont know how to do this.
[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taeb8.jpg)

this is my recyclerviewAdapter

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyView> {
private ArrayList<String> ex_name;
private ArrayList<Integer> ex_img;
private Context context;


public myAdapter(ArrayList<String> ex_name, ArrayList<Integer> ex_img, Context context) {
    this.ex_name = ex_name;
    this.ex_img = ex_img;
    this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public myAdapter.MyView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    return new MyView(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myAdapter.MyView holder, int position) {
    holder.ex_name.setText(ex_name.get(position));
    holder.ex_img.setImageResource(ex_img.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return ex_name.size();
}


public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView ex_name;
    public ImageView ex_img;
    public Button add, remove;

    public MyView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ex_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_exeName);
        ex_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_exeImg);
        add = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_btn);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                add.setText("Added");
                remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                remove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                add.setText("Add");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is my MainActivity

```
  private RecyclerView recycler_view;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private ArrayList<String> ex_name;
private ArrayList<Integer> ex_img;
private String select_ex_name;

Intent intent;
TextView exName;
Button next;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);
    exName = findViewById(R.id.exe_name);
    next = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
    intent = getIntent();
    ex_name = new ArrayList<>();
    ex_img = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    select_ex_name = intent.getStringExtra("Excercise_name");

    if (select_ex_name.equals("biceps")) {
        exName.setText("Biceps");
        ex_name.add("Fat-Grip Hammer Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.bicpes_1);
        ex_name.add("EZ-Bar Preacher Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_2);
        ex_name.add("Reverse Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_3);
        ex_name.add("Wide-Grip Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_4);
        ex_name.add("Close-Grip Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_5);
        ex_name.add("Hammer Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_6);
        ex_name.add("Dip");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_7);
        ex_name.add("Behind-the-Back Cable Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_8);
        ex_name.add("Side Curl with Band");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.biceps_9);

    } else if (select_ex_name.equals("chest")) {
        exName.setText("Chest");
        ex_name.add("Barbell Bench Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_1);
        ex_name.add("Dumbbell Bench Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_2);
        ex_name.add("Smith Machine Incline Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_3);
        ex_name.add("Incline Dumbbell Flye");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_4);
        ex_name.add("Cable Crossover");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_5);
        ex_name.add("Incline Dumbbell Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_6);
        ex_name.add("Chest Press Machine");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_7);
        ex_name.add("Dumbbell Flye");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_8);
        ex_name.add("Low-Cable Crossover");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.chest_9);
    } else if (select_ex_name.equals("back")) {
        exName.setText("Back");
        ex_name.add("Deadlift");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_1);
        ex_name.add(" Incline Dumbbell Row");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_2);
        ex_name.add("Trap-Bar Deadlift");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_3);
        ex_name.add("Cable Row");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_4);
        ex_name.add("Yates Row");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_5);
        ex_name.add(" Bentover Row to Neck");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_6);
        ex_name.add("Close-Grip Pull-Down");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_7);
        ex_name.add(" Single-Arm Dumbbell Row");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.back_8);


    } else if (select_ex_name.equals("triceps")) {
        exName.setText("Triceps");
        ex_name.add("Diamond Pushup");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_1);
        ex_name.add("Neutral-Grip Triceps Extension");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_2);
        ex_name.add("Reverse Curl");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_3);
        ex_name.add("Pullover/Triceps Extension");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_4);
        ex_name.add("Decline Triceps Extension");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_5);
        ex_name.add("Close-Grip Bench Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_6);
        ex_name.add(" Lying Triceps Extension");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_7);
        ex_name.add("Underhand Kickback");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.tri_8);

    } else if (select_ex_name.equals("legs")) {
        exName.setText("Legs");
        ex_name.add("Leg Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.legs1);
        ex_name.add("Pause Squat");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_2);
        ex_name.add("Reverse Lunge");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_3);
        ex_name.add("Dumbbell Squat");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_4);
        ex_name.add("Barbell Hip Thrust");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_5);
        ex_name.add("Seated Calf Raise");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_6);
        ex_name.add("Front Squat");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_7);
        ex_name.add("Romanian Deadlift");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_8);
        ex_name.add("Squart");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.leg_9);
    } else if (select_ex_name.equals("shoulder")) {
        exName.setText("Shoulder");
        ex_name.add("Barbell Overhead Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_1);
        ex_name.add("Standing Dumbbell Fly");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_2);
        ex_name.add(" Face Pull");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_3);
        ex_name.add("High Pull");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_4);
        ex_name.add("Seated Dumbbell Clean");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_5);
        ex_name.add(" Clean and Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_6);
        ex_name.add("Snatch-Grip High Pull");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_7);
        ex_name.add("Machine Shoulder Press");
        ex_img.add(R.drawable.shoulder_8);

    }
    recycler_view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new myAdapter(ex_name, ex_img, exerciseActivity.this);
    recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you can add item to arraylist then send arraylist with Bundle and Intent

Comment: Make an interface, gets a callback in main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you might consider using an json file asset to instantiate your different lists. this would make editing your items easier in future.

Next is taht you migth consider using fragments and Navigation as your app might have several screens that need to transport information from one to another.

By using the mentioned above your code to transfere simple data from one screen to another will look like this

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_screenA_to_screenB,bundleOf(Pair("selected_items", selected) // where selected might be an array
```

but now to the real stuff.

I thought that would result in an application state, so your state have to be tracked at an central position to be displayed at any position in your app.

So to do that you dont need to transfere your data directly to the next screen, a better aproach would be to move the data into a model.

By that any selection or action that requires data to be changed would be done on the model. Now that the model has got any action that have to be done. you could change the screen without even need to transfere data to the next one.

But how do i do that , you might ask? take a deep breath and here is a link to the guides that might solve your problems and keep your app easy to maintaine.

[Navigation using Navigation controller](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

[Using a shared viewmodel to exchange data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

and finally:
[Using Lifecycleobserver to load and save your data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

In onBindViewHolder() create a setOnClicklisterner and through the setOnclicklisterner create intent and send the information to the mainactivity.